# how to add a (big)difference between to dates to another date

Tags: java, date, jython, maximo

In a Jython script I want to move a date with the same amount an another date is changed. So in my script I get two variables:
scheduledDate and scheduledDate_previous

Both are java Date objects. I want to apply the difference to another Date: reservationDate

The problem is that with big differences, I get a 'cannot convert to integer'-error on the calendar.add() function. Here's my code:

```
from java.util import Date
form java.util import Calendar

myDiff = int(scheduledDate.getTime() - scheduledDate_previous.getTime())

reservationCal = Calendar.getInstance()
reservationCal.setTime(reservationDate)

reservationCal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, myDiff)

reservationDate = reservationCal.getTime()
```

If the difference between two dates becomes to large, the myDiff is no longer an Int, but a Big Int
(note that it can also be a negative number!)
So I tried something like this:

```
reservationCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, int(myDiff / 60000) )
```

I don't need that insane presicion anyway. But this didn't work all the time. **EDIT** It would result in a 'add(): second arg cant be coerced to an int'-error Which seemed fair since if you had a weird difference the division could result in a float. So I tried this:

```
from java.lang import Math
reservationCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, int(math.floor(myDiff / 60000)))
```

I still get an error like:

TypeError: unsupported operant type(s) for: 'java.math.BigInterger' and 'int'

The weird thing is that I don't get this error when I change the date a few days. It happens when I change it 3 months. User are able to change the date and time. They need to change it within a few years.

due to compatibility issues the machine is still on java 32 bit 1.6.0_25. It uses jython 2.5.2

Is there a solution or do I need different approuch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320857/642706) correctly solves the direct problem raised in the Question. This answer is a bonus, an alternate avenue to accomplish the goal of calculating and applying elapsed time.

Doing this kind of date-time work is much easier if using either of these libraries:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)
  (built into Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310))

The old date-time classes (java.util.Date, .Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat) bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them. If required you can convert to-and-fro with either library listed above.

## Joda-Time

The code example below is using Joda-Time 2.5.

### Elapsed Time

You can count elapsed time in either of two ways:

- **Calendar** style
  Number of months, weeks, days, and such.
- **Stopwatch** style
  Total number of milliseconds, as if measured with a running [stopwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopwatch).

These two ways to measure elapsed time may give different results! This code example shows both.

### Time Zone

Unlike j.u.Date, a `DateTime` object in Joda-Time actually knows its own assigned time zone. That is crucial if you count elapsed time by the calendar style (months, days, and so on). Note how this example uses Montréal, Québec time zone (arbitrarily chosen).

### Example Code

```
// Simulate inputs, a trio of java.util.Date objects.
java.util.Date dateStart = new DateTime( 2014 , 1 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC ).toDate();
java.util.Date dateStop = new DateTime( 2014 , 3 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC ).toDate();
java.util.Date dateTarget = new DateTime( 2014 , 7 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC ).toDate();

// Convert inputs to Joda-Time
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Or DateTimeZone.UTC.
DateTime start = new DateTime( dateStart , timeZone );
DateTime stop = new DateTime( dateStop , timeZone );
DateTime target = new DateTime( dateTarget , timeZone );

// Determine elapsed time in three fashions: (a) pair of points on timeline, (b) An amount of weeks, days, hours, and such, and (c) actual milliseconds.
Interval interval = new Interval( start , stop );
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
Duration duration = interval.toDuration();

// Add elapsed time to target date-time. Show results of adding either period or duration.
DateTime laterByPeriod = target.plus( period );
DateTime laterByDuration = target.plus( duration );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateStart: " + dateStart ); // BEWARE: j.u.Date objects are in UTC by definition, but "toString" method applies the JVM's current default time zone. Misleading!
System.out.println( "dateStop: " + dateStop );
System.out.println( "dateTarget: " + dateTarget );

System.out.println( "start: " + start );
System.out.println( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println( "target: " + target );

System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "duration: " + duration );

System.out.println( "laterByPeriod: " + laterByPeriod );  // Notice the change in offset because of DST (Daylight Saving Time) in Québec.
System.out.println( "laterByDuration: " + laterByDuration );
```

When run.

```
dateStart: Wed Jan 01 16:00:00 PST 2014
dateStop: Sat Mar 01 16:00:00 PST 2014
dateTarget: Mon Jun 30 17:00:00 PDT 2014
start: 2014-01-01T19:00:00.000-05:00
stop: 2014-03-01T19:00:00.000-05:00
target: 2014-06-30T20:00:00.000-04:00
interval: 2014-01-01T19:00:00.000-05:00/2014-03-01T19:00:00.000-05:00
period: P2M
duration: PT5097600S
laterByPeriod: 2014-08-30T20:00:00.000-04:00
laterByDuration: 2014-08-28T20:00:00.000-04:00
```

Comment: thx for this example. I cant use datetime because I'm stuck on java 1.6. I'm not sure if I can install joda-time. I will check though.

Comment: **Joda-Time 2.x runs on Java 5, 6, 7, and 8.** For Java 4, use Joda-Time 1.x continues to be available but may not be updated, so you may need to manually update the time-zone data (the ["Olsen database"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `long` (64-bit integer) rather than an `int` (32-bit integer). As described in the [Tutorial by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: Hi, due to compatibility issues the machine is still on java 32 bit 1.6.0_25. It uses jython 2.5.2
I've changed the code a bit, and the problem is the division. Even  myDiff = long( myDiff / long(60000)) results in the unsupported operant types for 'java.math.Biginterger'  and 'long'. If I just use long for myDiff (and keep it in milliseconds) I get an error like: and(): second arg cant be coerced to int

Comment: I suspect you are mishandling the syntax of `long` primitives. Use an uppercase `L` after a numeric literal. Casting is done with the type in parens, such as `(long)myIntVar`. Examples: `long x = 789L;` and `long y = ( x / 60000L );`